# Как сделать форматированный ввод TextField?

Tags: swift, xcode

Нужно организовать форматированный ввод в TextField, чтобы после каждого 4го символа ставился пробел (пример: "1234 5678 1234 1111"). Есть ли какие нибудь встроенные функции swift для реализации данной задачи? Или нужно в тупую при каждом изменении TextField проверять на ввод 4го символа и вставлять пробел?

Answer (score 1):

Встроенных функций насколько мне известно нет, выход - делать самописный вариант или использовать готовые решения ([например](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios))